# SQL Server Replication Issue

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication

I have two locations that was replicating data using sql server merge replication process. I upgraded the db and now I am trying to setup the replication again on the new database. However, I am concern about how do I keep the data that has not been sync during the offline period such that when the replication is backup all data can be correctly merged and updated. Otherwise data will be lost between the target/subscriber database.

Is there an approach I should take to prevent this or How should I go about merging the data before or after replication.

Answer (score 0):

Before restoring merge replication between new/upgraded databases you need to make sure these databases are fully synchronized BEFORE you initiate replication otherwise non-merged data at subscribers may get lost.

I have already provided the detailed workaround for such problem in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55716239/5857386 .

Hope it helps.